# Uploading to Cloud Storage - am I missing something obvious?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, image-uploading

I'm trying to find a fast way to upload big folders to Google cloud storage. When I do it via the web browser, it often can't handle the size.

So I've been trying to use SDK Shell.

I write

```
gsutil cp C:\Folder\Sub folder - name  gs://bucketname/
```

I get 
*`No urls matched C:\Folder`*

Then I put the file name in quotes

```
gsutil cp C:\"Folder\Sub folder - name"  gs://bucketname/
```

I get told
*`unrecognised scheme name gs`*

I've had a couple of friends look at it, they have no idea. I feel like I've tried so many iterations. Obviously I've missed something super basic? Any thoughts? It's a virtual machine running windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `-r` flag

> The -R and -r options are synonymous. Causes directories,
>                    buckets, and bucket subdirectories to be copied recursively.
>                    If you neglect to use this option for an upload, gsutil will
>                    copy any files it finds and skip any directories. Similarly,
>                    neglecting to specify this option for a download will cause
>                    gsutil to copy any objects at the current bucket directory
>                    level, and skip any subdirectories.

```
gsutil cp -r  C:\Folder\sub-folder-name  gs://bucketname/
```